# Como alterar o "Id" do System.Web.UI.WebControls(TreeNode) dinâmico no c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Sou novo no assunto, e estou criando uma estrutura dinâmica de treenodes, nesta estrutura o id dos nodes, está implementando automaticamente, mas gostaria de definir o id do nodes, portanto não tem a propriedade Id, neste nodes. Se alguém pode me ajudar eu agradeço. (Obs: Os node estão sendo inserido em uma "asp:TreeView").
segue parte do código.

```
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
protected void treenodes()
{
 TreeNode tree = new Treenode();
 tree.text = "My TreeNode";
 Tree.value = 1;
 tree.SelctAction = SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.Expand;
 //aqui são os childNodes
 Treenode subTree = new TreeNode();
 subtree.text = "My TreeNode";
 subTree.value = 1.1;
 tree.ChildNodes.Add(subTree);
 TreeView.Nodes.Add(tree);
}
```

Comment: Não existe propriedade `Id`, mas existe a `Name`.

Comment: @JoãoMartins acredito que a propriedade Name, e só para treeNodes para system.Windows.Form, neste caso estou em uma estrutura system.web.UI.Controls, e não apresenta nem um destas propriedades.

Comment: Tem razão, tinha ideia que existia. Mas pode utilizar a propriedade `Value`, que segundo a ajuda serve para armazenar informação relativa ao nodo e não é visível no UI. Vi que já está a utilizar, então pode definir isso como o seu `Id` de nodo.

Comment: Sim, tem a propriedade Value, mas por algum motivo que no momento é desconhecido ela esta sendo alterada pelo treenode, esta apresentando valor vazio;